# WordPress Custom Fields w/ Shortcodes to use in Posts and Pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to WordPress but learning very fast. I started my first plugin that creates a custom admin menu. One of the submenus is named Business Profile. Here is what I want to do:

1). Add custom fields to the Business Profile to collection business info (ex: Business Name)
2). Each custom field needs a related shortcode
3). All shortcodes can be placed within content on Posts and Pages and replaced with the custom field value.

I'm looking for a tutorial or some direction on how to do the above without the use of a plugin. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want to store and retrieve only one business information.

```
function sample_register_my_custom_menu_page(){
    add_menu_page( 
        __( 'Business Profile', 'business-profile' ),
        'Business Profile',
        'manage_options',
        'business-profile-settings',
        'business_profile_settings_page',
        80
    ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'sample_register_my_custom_menu_page' );

function business_profile_settings_page(){
    if ($_POST) {
        // Form Submission Processing
        $business_profile = array();
        $business_profile['business_name'] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['business_name']);

        update_option('business_profile_details', $business_profile);
    }
    // Form View
    // Add your html form here
    $business_profile = get_option( 'business_profile_details' );
    // Get your saved data and pre fill your form.
}
```

You can further use [add_shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/) to get the data from the options and display it the post.

Note: Use wp_options to store this data only if this is a single data set. If you want to save data of multiple business you may need to use a custom post for it.